# Convert Date String to another Date string with different format

Tags: c#, date-conversion, date-parsing

I need to convert an string date with format `yyyyMMdd` to a date string with format `MM/dd/yyyy`. Which is the best to do it?

I'm doing this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

But I'm not sure, i think there must be a better way. What do you think?

Comment: your way is the best way I think.

Comment: havent yet thought of better way than this :)

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to _reformat_ a string? Sounds as if you are actually formatting a "date-string" from database, am i right? Then store it as `datetime` in the first place.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are doing is fine.

Probably you can improve it by using [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) and on successful parsing, format the `DateTime` object in other format.

```
string dateString = "20130916";
DateTime parsedDateTime;
string formattedDate;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMdd", 
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                    DateTimeStyles.None, 
                    out parsedDateTime))
{
    formattedDate = parsedDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
else
{
       Console.WriteLine("Parsing failed");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your way is totally OK.You may try doing this:-

```
string res = "20130908";
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(res, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

Just for reference from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx):-

> The DateTime.ParseExact(String, String, IFormatProvider) method parses
>   the string representation of a date, which must be in the format
>   defined by the format parameter.

Comment: The question specifies `yyyyMMdd`... your example is exactly the same but with `yyyyddMM`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is in fact the best (of course better using `TryParseExact`), however **looks like your input string is in the correct format (convertible to `DateTime`)**, you just want to re-format it, I think using some **string method** will help. But I would like to use `Regex` here:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "^(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})$", "$2/$3/$1");
//E.g
input = "20130920";
output = "09/20/2013";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string date = "01/08/2008";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);     //or       
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(date, culture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal); //or       
// create date time 2008-03-09 16:05:07.123
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 3, 9, 16, 5, 7, 123); //or
```

**Now Format as you like with** `dt` ...

```
String.Format("{0:y yy yyy yyyy}", dt);  // "8 08 008 2008"   year
String.Format("{0:M MM MMM MMMM}", dt);  // "3 03 Mar March"  month
String.Format("{0:d dd ddd dddd}", dt);  // "9 09 Sun Sunday" day
String.Format("{0:h hh H HH}",     dt);  // "4 04 16 16"      hour 12/24
String.Format("{0:m mm}",          dt);  // "5 05"            minute
String.Format("{0:s ss}",          dt);  // "7 07"            second
String.Format("{0:f ff fff ffff}", dt);  // "1 12 123 1230"   sec.fraction
String.Format("{0:F FF FFF FFFF}", dt);  // "1 12 123 123"    without zeroes
String.Format("{0:t tt}",          dt);  // "P PM"            A.M. or P.M.
String.Format("{0:z zz zzz}",      dt);  // "-6 -06 -06:00"   time zone
```

Format part from As from [www.csharp-examples.net](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)